# Completely lost at K&R exerceise 1-24

Tags: c

> Exercise 1-24. Write a program to check a C program for rudimentary
> syntax errors like unmatched parentheses, brackets and braces. Don't
> forget about quotes, both single and double, escape sequences, and
> comments. (This program is hard if you do it in full generality.)

I'm trying to find a solution for this and am completely lost with the only outcome being a big headache. How can I account for cases like this? :

`({ ) }` or `{( } )` or `((({(({}})))))`

They're my biggest obstacle.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I account for cases like this? : `({ ) }` or `{( } )`

Typically you'd deal with something like this using a stack. When you read in one of the characters you care about matching, if it's an open ( `(`, `{` or `[`) you push it on the stack. If it's a close you check it against the top of the stack to see if it matches.

Comment: Another version is to _push_ the "matching close character" for any "open character" (that is already known.)... When any one of the 3 close characters is encountered, it's easy to simply "pop & compare"...

Comment: What does a mismatch tell you? What about if you get to the end of the string and the stack is non-empty? If it's empty?

Comment: Stack based pushdown automata - Read about it on Wikipedia then go and read about it in lots of other sources. These are fundamental to understanding CS. push ( , push {, push [, ..... ] pop match, } pop match, ) pop match. Mismatch is error. I really mean understand this solution, and how to code it, it is very fundamental.